# Confusion about Fourier transform and fractional Sobolev space definition

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the fractional Sobolev spaces defined as $$
W^{s,p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right):=\left\{ u\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right):\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(1+\left|\xi\right|^{sp}\right)\left|\widehat{u}\left(\xi\right)\right|^{p}d\xi<+\infty\right\} $$ where $s>0$, $1\leq p\leq+\infty$ and $\widehat{u}$ is the Fourier transform of $u$. From what I understand, these spaces, known also as Bessel potential spaces, are well-known and studied, but I have some trouble to understand the definition. The Fourier transform of $u\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ is, in general, a distribution, defined as $$\widehat{u}\left[\varphi\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(x\right)\widehat{\varphi}\left(x\right)dx$$ where $\varphi$ is a suitable function, for example $\varphi$ belongs to the Schwarz space. So, what is the meaning of $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(1+\left|\xi\right|^{sp}\right)\left|\widehat{u}\left(\xi\right)\right|^{p}d\xi\,\,?$$ More precisely, how can we integrate a distribution written as a funciton of $\xi$? Maybe it is a simple question but I cannot find an answer in the text I studied.

Comment: Part of the definition is that $\hat{u}$ is a function lying in that weighted $L^p$ space.

Comment: @RhysSteele In the books I have read it is not written anywhere that, in the definition, $u$ is such that its Fourier transform is a function. Instead, it is written that, if $p>2$, then we are working with a distribution. Do you have any reference where this fact is specified for the definition of these spaces?

Comment: Your reference specifies it. Part of writing down the condition $\int (1+|\xi|^{sp}) |\hat{u}(\xi)|^p d\xi < \infty$ is that the integral makes sense in the first place which means that $u$ is a special kind of distribution with nice fourier transform. Note that this does not mean that $u$ itself is a function.

Comment: @RhysSteele I'm not sure that what you said is the right answer. Consider that, in other texts, I saw $\left(1+\left|\xi\right|^{sp}\right)^{1/p}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform. Is it possible that the definition implicitly require to extend the classical $L^{p}$ norm to distributions, somehow?

Comment: Well since $\hat{u}$ is another notation for $\mathcal{F}[u]$ and saying that $(1+|\xi|^{sp})\hat{u} \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is just saying that that thing is an (equivalence class of) function(s) with finite $L^p$ norm, your other texts also agree with what I said. If you really want to, you can extend the $L^p$ norm to an extended norm (i.e. a 'norm' valued in $[0,\infty]$) on distributions by saying its the usual $L^p$ norm if applied to a function with finite $L^p$-norm and is infinite otherwise, but that is again just a different set of words for the same definition I wrote.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you but I'm still skeptical regarding your thesis. I'm reading the book "Sobolev spaces" by Adams, Fournier right now, I hope to find something there.

Comment: Wikipedia and Adams provide definition different from yours: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Bessel_potential_spaces It relies on tempered distributions (case $p \neq 2$). You need 2 applications of Fourier transform in definition (not one).

Comment: @dsh I'm referring to the definition here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.10245.pdf, definition $2.2$.

Comment: It does not look like authors rely on this definition in substantial way. Did you find a place where this definition is used in a proof?

Comment: @dsh Not really, I just see proofs and applications for the case $p=2$ but this case is somehow special.

Comment: This definition is also inconsistent for $s=0$ as Fourier transform is from $L^q$ when defined.