# Confusion about definition of Fractional Sobolev space II

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I'm studying fractional Sobolev spaces and, similarly to a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849884/confusion-about-fourier-transform-and-fractional-sobolev-space-definition), I have some troubles to understand some definitions.

Consider the [Bessel potential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Bessel_potential_spaces), defined as $$
H^{s,p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right):=\left\{ u\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right):\,\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]\right]\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right\},$$ where $s>0$, $\mathcal{F}\left[\cdot\right]$ is the Fourier transform and $1<p<+\infty$, equipped with the norm $$\left\Vert \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]\right]\right\Vert _{L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)}.$$ Now, my problem is to understand what is, explicitly, such norm. This is what I did: the Fourier transform of a $L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ function could not be a function, so we need to use the distributional definition of such integral transform. Hence $$\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]=\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]_{\phi}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(x\right)\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\left(x\right)dx$$ where $\phi(x)$ is a test fuction. The product of a smooth function with a distribution is always defined, since, if $\psi$ is smooth, then $$\left\langle \psi u,\phi\right\rangle =\left\langle u,\psi\phi\right\rangle $$ hence it should be $$\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(x\right)\left(1+\left|x\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\left(x\right)dx$$
because $$\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]=\left\langle u,\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\right\rangle $$ and so $$\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]=\left\langle \left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}u,\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\right\rangle =\left\langle u,\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\right\rangle. $$
Hence $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(x\right)\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\left(1+\left|y\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\left(y\right)\right]\left(x\right)dx=:\int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(x\right)\tilde{v}_{\phi}\left(x\right)dx$$ and finally $$\left\Vert \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]\right]\right\Vert _{L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)}=\sup\left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}}u\left(x\right)\tilde{v}_{\phi}\left(x\right)dx:\,\left\Vert \phi\right\Vert _{q}\leq1\right\},$$

where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$. I'm really not sure if this ideas are correct, and I would like to know if there are some mistakes.

Comment: I don't really understand what is happening in the line after "hence it should be". Are you writing $\mathcal F[u]$ to mean $\int \mathcal F[u]\phi \,dx$? In that case, I don't see why the $(\ldots)^{s/2}$ factor is not transformed along with $\phi$? Maybe you could explain this better, if I got it wrong?

Comment: @DominikS I use the fact the product of a smooth function with a distribution is a distribution, using the fact that the product of a smooth funciton with a test function is a test function. In such case, the test function is the Fourier transform of $\phi$, so I have to multiply the smooth function with the $\mathcal{F}[\phi]$. But I am not sure I am right.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Hmm, I still think that something is not right there. $\mathcal F[u]$ is a functional that can be applied to a test function $\phi$, and $\langle \mathcal F[u], \phi$ is the application to the test function, and a complex number. So they are not the same.

Comment: In the next line ("and so"), I would use the brackets and application to $\phi$ from the very beginning. It would start with $\langle (1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal F[u], \phi\rangle = \langle\mathcal F[u],  (1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\phi\rangle =  \langle u,\mathcal F[  (1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\phi]\rangle$. You see that the muliplicative factor should be included in the transform, and not left out like in your operation.

Comment: @DominikS But  what is the definition of $\left\langle \left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right],\phi\right\rangle $? The Fourier transform of $u$ is $\left\langle u,\mathcal{F}\left[\phi\right]\right\rangle $, so it is already in itself a scalar product. Maybe I missing something...

Comment: This seems to be the source of confusion: There is a unique distribution $w$ that satisfies $\langle w, \phi\rangle = \langle u, \mathcal F[\phi]\rangle$ for all $\phi$. We call this $w$ the Fourier-Transform of $u$, and write $\mathcal F[u]$. In other words, $\mathcal F[u]$ is a distribution, and its action on a test function is given by $\mathcal F[u](\phi) :=\langle u, \mathcal F[\phi]\rangle$.

Comment: Recall that for $u\in L^1$, $\mathcal F[u]$ is a continuous function (and also a distribution), and its action on a test function is $\langle \mathcal F[u], \phi\rangle$.

Comment: Note that for $u,\phi\in C_0^\infty$, you can compute $\mathcal F[u]$ explicitly, and you can verify that $\int \mathcal F[u]\phi\,d\xi = \int u\mathcal F[\phi]\,d\xi$ (this is just basic calculus), and this _motivates_ the generalisation to distributions via test-functions.

Comment: @DominikS Ok, so, if $(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2})^{s/2}\mathcal{F}[u]=\left\langle u,\mathcal{F}\left[\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\phi\right]\right\rangle $, then $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\left(1+\left|\cdot\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}\left[u\right]\right]$ it is just $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x)\left(1+\left|x\right|^{2}\right)^{s/2}\phi(x)dx$, and so we have to consider the $L^{p}$ norm of such distribution, am I right?

Comment: Again, in your comment's first equation: The l.h.s. is a distribution (you have not applied it to $\phi$), the r.h.s. is a complex number (=the application of the distribution to the $\phi$). This is important: $\mathcal F[u]$ is a distribution, and $\langle \mathcal F[u], \phi\rangle$ is the application of the distribution to $\phi$. _They are not the same!_

Comment: @DominikS Oh, ok, now I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that $\mathcal F[u]$ might not be a function any more. However, why not work with distributions directly? You know that $\mathcal F[u]$ is defined for any tempered distribution, and the result will be a tempered distribution again. Therefore $(1+|\cdot|^{2})^{s/2}\mathcal{F}[u]$ will be a temp. distribution again, and you may apply the inverse Fourier transform, i.e. $u_s:=\mathcal F^{-1}[(1+|\cdot|^{2})^{s/2}\mathcal{F}[u]]$ is well-defined and a tempered distribution.

Finally, $u\in H^{s,p}$ iff $u_s\in L^p$.

**Comment**: The factor $(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}$ in Fourier-space can be interpreted as a fractional derivative of the original function. To see this, recall that $\mathcal F[u'](\xi) = \mathrm{i}\xi \mathcal F[u](\xi)$. This illustrates the general fact that the asymptotic decay of $\mathcal F[u](\xi)$ as $|\xi|\to\pm\infty$ is closely linked to the smoothness of $u$. In particular, you could define $H^1(\mathbb R)$ as the set of all $L^2$-functions for which $$\mathcal F^{-1}\big[(1+\xi^2)^{1/2}\mathcal F[u](\xi)\big]\in L^2.$$
It really says that whenever the inverse transform (which always exists as a tempered distribution) also happens to be an $L^2$-function, the function is in $H^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to work with an "explicit" form of $u_{s}$, in particular I need an explicit formula involving $u$; this is the reason why I write all the passages in the question.